# NSString to treat "regular english alphabets" and characters like emoji or japanese uniformly

Tags: ios, unicode, nsstring, unicode-string

There is a textView in which I can enter Characters. characters can be a,b,c,d etc or a smiley face added using emoji keyboard.

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    NSLog(@"len:%lu",textField.length);
    NSLog(@"char:%c",[textField.text characterAtIndex:0]);
}
```

Currently , The above function gives following outputs

```
if textField.text = @"qq"
len:2
char:q

if textField.text = @"q"
len:3
char:=
```

What I need is

```
if textField.text = @"qq"
len:2
char:q

if textField.text = @"q"
len:2
char:
```

Any clue how to do this ?

Comment: What are you trying to do and what is the problem?

Comment: @Zaph : Problem is I have to paste only the first 4 characters of a string in a textField , and that 4 characters can be @"qqqq" or @""

Comment: OK, Apple screwed this up, textField.text.length returns the number of unichars. See my new answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Apple screwed up emoji (actually Unicode planes above 0) this becomes difficult. It seems it is necessary to enumerate through the composed character to get the actual length.

Note: The `NSString` method `length` does not return the number of characters but the number of code units (not characters) in unichars. See [NSString and Unicode - Strings - objc.io issue #9](http://www.objc.io/issue-9/unicode.html).

Example code:

```
NSString *text = @"qqqrrr";
int maxCharacters = 4;

__block NSInteger unicharCount = 0;
__block NSInteger charCount = 0;
[text enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, text.length)
                         options:NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences
                      usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
                          unicharCount += substringRange.length;
                          if (++charCount >= maxCharacters)
                              *stop = YES;
                      }];
NSString *textStart = [text substringToIndex: unicharCount];
NSLog(@"textStart: '%@'", textStart);
```

> textStart: 'qqq'

An alternative approach is to use utf32 encoding:

```
int byteCount = maxCharacters*4; // 4 utf32 characters
char buffer[byteCount];
NSUInteger usedBufferCount;
[text getBytes:buffer maxLength:byteCount usedLength:&usedBufferCount encoding:NSUTF32StringEncoding options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, text.length) remainingRange:NULL];
NSString * textStart = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:usedBufferCount encoding:NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding];
```

There is some rational for this in Session 128 - Advance Text Processing from 2011 WWDC.

Comment: thanks - I was able to get the length using `[string lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF32StringEncoding]/4` . How could I also get the character at appropriate index ?

Comment: if my input string is @"qqq" then after applying substring method i get "qqq?" . Where ? depicts partial emoji. When I pass this string with partial emoji to NSJSONSerialiation, it crashes.

Comment: Don't make assumptions of how NSString works. It is also wrong, "" is four bytes in utf-16 but "q" is just two bytes.

Comment: your solution seems looks quite nice. Thanks !

Comment: Please see the alternative approach as well. I apologize for not understanding the problem at first, I had even read the objc.io article but did not connect.

Comment: Great answer!
But for the newer emojis (with different colored faces, ...) only the 'enumerateSubstringsInRange' solution works. unicharCount for those new emojis is 5!

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did to cut a string with emoji characters

```
+(NSUInteger)unicodeLength:(NSString*)string{
    return [string lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF32StringEncoding]/4;
}

+(NSString*)unicodeString:(NSString*)string toLenght:(NSUInteger)len{

    if (len >= string.length){
        return string;
    }

    NSInteger charposition = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        NSInteger remainingChars = string.length-charposition;
        if (remainingChars >= 2){
            NSString* s = [string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(charposition,2)];
            if ([self unicodeLength:s] == 1){
                charposition++;
            }
        }
        charposition++;
    }
    return [string substringToIndex:charposition];
}
```

Comment: See selected answer. better solution !